# Insert TimeStamp in SQLite for Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following fields

```
1> WorkName - Varchar

2> TimeStap
```

I wanted to create a Table with the above fields.

1. What will be the TimeStamp datatype
2. How can I insert timestamp values to the table.
3. What will the timestamp value while inserting data or how to fetch the timestamp.

I have worked on SQLite but don't have any experience on adding TimeStamp as a field to the table & adding values to that.

What kind of `CREATE` & `INSERT` statements should I use?

Comment: Also interested in this topic. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are limited datatypes available in a Sqlite Database, so the one I find useful for dates is integer - this will accept long values (dynamically adjusts its size) so for dates store the milliseconds value of a date and the date can be easily reconsituted when reading the millisecond values back out of the database.

Comment: This is the method that i was using, i was just using the epoch timer and just storing that int date and then reconstructing the actual time when needed. I was just wondering if there was a better method. Thanks

Comment: Thanks John & prolink for your comments

Answer (score 1):

I create timestamp by this:

```
/**
 *
 * @return yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss formate date as string
 */
public static String getCurrentTimeStamp(){
    try {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date()); // Find todays date

        return currentTimeStamp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Java.sql.Timestamp class` as the column datatype of your table in a SQL database.

Since `SQLiteDatabase` class doesn't support a `put()` method for `Timestamp` variables, use the `getTime()` method in the class to insert the corresponding milliseconds of that time as a `long` value.(SQLiteDatabase does have a `put()` method for `long` type)
[Open this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime()) for the method reference.