# Insert timestamp column in database android

Tags: android

How do you insert another column, data/timestamp in a database and display it in the Listview existing in   database android  ? I have the code of my database here:

```
public class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String KEY_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";

public Helper(Context context) {
    super(context, "ContactManager", null, 1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE contact(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 1   ,nom TEXT, KEY_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contact");
    onCreate(db);
}

public void AddContact(int id , String nom , String dtNoteDay)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    SimpleDateFormat fmtDate = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd hh:mm:ss");
    dtNoteDay = fmtDate.format(new Date());
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(nom);
    while (s.hasNextLine()){
        String line = s.nextLine().replaceAll("[^\\d]","") ;
        if (line.trim().length()>0) {
            cv.put("nom",line);
            cv.put("KEY_TIMESTAMP",dtNoteDay);
            db.insert("contact", null, cv);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4867083/9426046), I think it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ALTER TABLE` command in the `onUpgrade` method to add a column. Since there is no specific data type conforming to timestamp, an integer can be used instead.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE contact ADD COLUMN Timestamp INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
}
```

When it comes to rendering the column values in ListView, a simple way to accomplish this is to use a cursor and query the table accordingly, further, you can add the values to an array and pass it to an array adapter or custom adapter.

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select Timestamp from contact");
while(c.moveToNext()){
 arr.add(new String(c.getInteger(index_of_column_timestamp)));
}

listViewInstance.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr));
```

Comment: can I use the put function which will insert the data into the database because I use the database for the creation of the new column for timestamp

Comment: You may do so after the column is added/created.